# Are welded-handled stock pots safe?

Tags: equipment, cookware, shopping, pot, kitchen-safety

I'm shopping for a new 16 to 20 quart induction-compatible stock pot and seem to be having a hard time finding one that has handles that are not welded.  I've read in various Amazon reviews that welds can weaken and break, and if true, nobody wants a pot of scalding water spilling all over themselves.

Is this true?  Assuming so, is there an induction stock pot that has screwed or riveted handles?

The two pots I'm looking at are the [Update International SPS-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X1JO6W) and the [Winware Stainless Steel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AS81BG) one.

Comment: the information you seek is on the pages you gave links to...read further to the bottom and into the customer reviews and Q&A.

Comment: Long story short: As long as it was properly welded (read: manufactured), you don't need to worry.

Comment: If the handles are just spot-welded on, the spot weld is not unlikely to be the eventual breaking site - either by just tearing off or rusting off because the metallurgy at the weld site is just not as rustproof as the rest- lost a few cheap pots to exactly that happening, until now just considered it the way these things break when their useful life is up and not a safety issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there were stock pots manufactured with handles that broke off, they would likely have been recalled by the CPSC.

It [appears](https://www.google.com/search?q=stockpot%20handle%20recall%20site%3awww.cpsc.gov) that the CPSC has only ever recalled [one stock pot](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Recalls/2009/Stainless-Steel-Pots-Recalled-by-Ocean-State-Jobbers-Due-to-Burn-Hazard/) that was based on a single report of a handle breaking off.  The problematic stock pot was sold by a liquidation company.  Based on this, I'd assume that any NSF certified stock pot that you buy from a reputable retailer is going to be safe.